# Bandwidth controlled tests in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

I have a business requirement wherein I want to simulate bandwidth related load tests targeting different bandwidth and in a steady manner.Like we have ultimate thread group in JMeter to control the users providing a steady ramp up at given time. Do we have any such element/plugin to control enormous bandwidth like 70 Gigabit/sec in JMeter or BlazeMeter?

Answer (score 1):

"Bandwidth" is basically the sum of sent and received bytes so it mostly depends on request and response time.

If you have 1 megabyte request/response - in order to simulate [70 gigabit you will need to send 8750 requests](https://www.gbmb.org/gbps-to-mbs) at the same moment.

So I would recommend executing your test plan with 1 virtual user and 1 iteration and look into last 2 columns of the [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener

[image: JMeter Aggregate Report Bandwidth]

This is how many (kilo/mega/giga)bytes your test produces for the test duration. Divide it by test duration in seconds to find out the bandwidth "per second" and divide 70 gigabits by that number to find out how many requests you will need to make.

Most probably you will need to go for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) (unless you have a single machine with 100-gigabit network adapter capable of running required amount of virtual users)